# Is it possible to draw these charts with nvd3 or similar?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

In a project I'm working on right now, which requires showing lots of charts, we've been using [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/) javascript library quite successfully so far.

One of the new features we are adding now requires us to render this kind of chart:

[image]

Which is supposed to be a distribution chart (A + B + C + D = 100%). I don't know how to call that kind of chart.

As far as I know there's no way to draw that chart using [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/), but I may be wrong.

**Does anyone know a way to draw that kind of chart using [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/) or any other library?**

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE***: I've learned that this kind of chart is called "rose chart", "polar area chart" or "coxcomb chart".

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/2297636) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a few samples similar to you requirement that might help get and idea. It uses the [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) framework

- [D3 Pie charts with grid lines](http://bl.ocks.org/mccannf/3994129)
- [Creating a Polar Area Diagram (Radial Bar Chart)](http://archive.is/dJu9k)
- [Smooth Transitioning of Polar Area Diagram](http://archive.is/Epuzn)

And here's a [The Big List of D3.js Examples](http://christopheviau.com/d3list/)

Hope it helps

Comment: The second two links are dead